# Help with websnapr thumbs

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone tell me how to get websnapr.com screen shoot in inside a MySQL loop

**This is the code i put and its giving a error**

Error: Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in G:\MyServer\xampp\htdocs\testproject\test_template.php on line 35

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo  '<div class="c_thumb">';
echo  '<script type="text/javascript">''wsr_snapshot''(''http:''//'.$row['url'].', ''websnapr API Key'',' 'Size'')';
echo  '</script>''</div>';}
```

**Code provided by websnapr.com**

```
<script type="text/javascript">wsr_snapshot('http://URL', 'websnapr API Key', 'Size');</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: there's a mess with `'` symbols

Comment: can tell me how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
<?php

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
  echo  '<div class="c_thumb">';
  echo  '<script type="text/javascript">wsr_snapshot("http://' . $row['url'] . '", "websnapr API Key", "Size");';
  echo  '</script></div>';
}
```

Comment: I originally wrote my answer thinking that `wsr_snapshot` was a PHP function but I've noticed that it's a JavaScript function. I've updated the answer above.